# I have issue with back button - Making a Similar website to youtube

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, youtube

My code is based on youtube (i'm trying to figure out how youtube work) but there is problem with back button - i need to click back button 2 times to work and when i use back i cant use forward button again

This is the code:

index.php :

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['n']) && $_GET['n'] == "n"){
  f1();
}else{
  f2();
}
function f2(){
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>index</title>
  <script>
      function t(a) {
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.onload = function () {
              if ((xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 300) || xhr.status == 304) {
                  document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                  document.title = a;
              }
          };
          xhr.open("get", a, true);
          xhr.send(null);
          history.pushState({state:3}, a, a);
          this.oldHash = window.location.href;
          return false
      }
      function hashHandler(){
          this.oldHash = window.location.href;
          var that = this;
          var detect = function(){
              if(that.oldHash!=window.location.href){
                  t(window.location.href);
                  that.oldHash = window.location.href;
              }
          };
          this.Check = setInterval(function(){ detect() }, 100);
      }
      hashHandler();
  </script>
</head>
<body id="div1">
<a href="Test.php" onclick="return t('Test.php')">index</a>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
function f1(){
?>
<a href="Test.php" onclick="return t('Test.php')">index</a>
<?php
}
```

Test.php :

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['n']) && $_GET['n'] == "n"){
  f1();
}else{
  f2();
}
function f2(){
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script>
      function t(a) {
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.onload = function () {
              if ((xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 300) || xhr.status == 304) {
                  document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                  document.title = a;
              }
          };
          xhr.open("get", a, true);
          xhr.send(null);
          history.pushState({state:3}, a, a);
          this.oldHash = window.location.href;
          return false
      }
      function hashHandler(){
          this.oldHash = window.location.href;
          var that = this;
          var detect = function(){
              if(that.oldHash!=window.location.href){
                  t(window.location.href);
                  that.oldHash = window.location.href;
              }
          };
          this.Check = setInterval(function(){ detect() }, 100);
      }
      hashHandler();
  </script>
</head>
<body id="div1">
<a href="index.php" onclick="return t('index.php')">Test</a>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
function f1(){
?>
<a href="index.php" onclick="return t('index.php')">Test</a>
<?php
}
```

Please put this code in two separate PHP files
Thank you.